# The "cow-keeper"-story?

Tags: reference-request, sila, right-livelihood

My person remembers a possible common know story about a Brahman collecting as much as possible cow's leading to sorrows for poor. The Sublime Buddha approached him one day, gave a talk and later he released the cows.

It might be that's just a later tale not found in the scripts, my person just does not remember where having been come across aside in an illustrated "Children"-book.

Good if one likes to share messages on livelihood.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades but for release from this wheel]*

Comment: "Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades but for release from this wheel" What does this mean?

Comment: That is isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades but for release from this wheel, maybe?

Comment: That's what you said, but what does it mean?

Comment: Which word does good householder not understand?

Answer (score 3):

The following is somewhat like the posted question, but not exactly:

> [SN35.241:7.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.241/en/sujato#sn35.241:7.4): Sir, may I receive the going forth, the ordination in the Buddha’s presence?”

> [SN35.241:7.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.241/en/sujato#sn35.241:7.5): “Well then, Nanda, return the cows to their owners.”

> [SN35.241:7.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.241/en/sujato#sn35.241:7.6): “Sir, the cows will go back by themselves, since they love their calves.”

> [SN35.241:7.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.241/en/sujato#sn35.241:7.7): “Still, Nanda, you should return them to their owners.”

Here the Buddha emphasizes ethics in our relationships with others. The Noble Path starts with Right View.

Comment: ethics, relationship, SC... ironical, or, cow-release? Maybe good for feedback their. Sadhu for welmeant effort anyway, but Atma guesses being a commentary-story, Upasaka Karl.